# Externalizing knockout templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

i am using knockout.js and asp.netmvc. While i am familiar with knockout.js i am not sure how to externalize the templates. So,

1.)How to externalize knockout templates
2.)Is there a way to bundle the templates just like we bundle css and JS in MVC4

Comment: Can you clarify "externalize"?  Do you want them stored in a separate file -- and then merged in to your view?

Comment: Yeah. I want to store them in a separate file. The reason why i would like to store them in a separate file is so that i bundle them them. Not sure sure how to bundle them but yea. Also i can think later about placing them even in a CDN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen [Knockout External Templates](https://github.com/ifandelse/Knockout.js-External-Template-Engine)?

Answer (score 3):

With Razor as your view engine, you could create partial views for your templates and then include them with `Html.Partial()`:

```
<script type="text/html" id="person-template">
    @Html.Partial("person")
</script>
```